# Checking filesize before download of multiple files

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, uiprogressview

Im currently implementing an update feature into an app that I'm building. It uses NSUrlConnection and the NSURLConnectionDelegate to download the files and save them to the users device.

At the moment, 1 update item downloads multiple files but i want to display this download of multiple files using 1 UIProgressView. So my problem is, how do i get the expected content length of all the files i'm about to download? I know i can get the expectedContentLength of the NSURLResponse object that gets passed into the didReceiveResponse method but thats just for the file thats being downloaded.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having some kind of information file on your server, which actually gives you the total bytes. You could load that at first and then load your files. Then you can substract the loaded amount for each file from the total amount.

Another method would be to connect to all files at first, and cancel the connection after you received responses. Add the expected bytes of all files and then use that as a basis for showing the total progress while loading files.

Downside of #1: you have to manually keep track of the bytes.

Downside of #2: you'll have the double amount of requests, even though they get cancelled after the response.

Comment: Good idea. I think the first idea is probably the best, each update is  an NSDictionary object so i'll just add a property for the content size. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ASIhttp opensource framework widely used for this purpose,
here u just need to set progressview delegate..so it will keep updating your progress view

Try this
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/